# Sending data over ethernet from a Raspberry Pi to a c# program on a windows PC

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi

I'm working on an electronic tagging system, where there will be multiple places to read the tags which then updates a central server.

My problem is that I have actually no idea how to implement the data transfer portion of this solution. I was going to use a raspberry pi to receive the RFID signal and then transfer the tag's id along with a code for the receiver to a windows PC.

If you could point me in the right direction to a web tutorial or a textbook so that I could find how to do this that would be fantastic.

(also if you know what tags this post needs please feel free to fix them, I also have no idea what they should be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your RFID reader interfaces with Raspberry-Pi via serial port, the best approach would be to write a simple C program that received data from RFID reader via serial port and send it to your Windows server via TCP/UDP connection.

A bit of googling will give you ways about reading/writing on serial port and connecting to a server via TCP/UDP socket.

Comment: That was what I was leaning towards thanks for confirming it.